# Is it bad practice to implement a binary tree using leftChild and rightChild?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I haven't implemented binary for a long time, and recently got a requirement to do that (to demonstrate some code), and I started using:

```
@interface NSNode : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNode *leftChild;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNode *rightChild;
```

but later on, it seems that whenever I need to do something to both nodes, I need to write it twice -- once for the left child and once for the right child, unless if I make what needs to be done into an extra method, and pass the proper arguments carefully -- there will be a lot of extra methods just to accomplish this.

If it had been done by using an NSMutableArray

```
typedef enum {
    NSNodeLeft = 0,
    NSNodeRight
} NSNodeLeftOrRightSide;

@interface NSNode : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *children;
```

then I can always just use a loop to do something to both nodes:

```
for (NSNode *node in self.children) {
    // do something
}
```

Or if an index is needed to tell whether it is left or right child:

```
[self.children enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:
    ^(NSNode *node, NSUInteger nodeIndex, BOOL *stop) {
        // do something
    }
];
```

and the `nodeIndex` can be used to determined whether it is left or right child.

And what's more, this class can be easily extend to a tree with N-children.  Is this actually a better practice?  Is there any disadvantage except for a very small performance for using array?  (I chose `NSMutableArray` instead of `NSArray` because if we ever need to make this N-children, we don't need to change it to `NSMutableArray` all over the place).

Comment: Prefixing your class name with the vendor's prefix is far worse practice than this...

Comment: are you use?  I often see people doing `UINodeView` or something like that... should it be not-prefixed... or what should it be prefixed to (only when releasing it to the public to avoid name conflict?)

Comment: @JeremyL: You should prefix your classes, but you need to pick a unique prefix. Apple owns NS, CF, CA, UI, and a few other prefixes too. People often use their initials so JL might be a good choice for you.

Comment: @JeremyL He's absolutely sure and so am I.  [Read the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/iPhoneOSTechOverview/iPhoneOSFrameworks/iPhoneOSFrameworks.html): “Avoid using any of the specified prefixes in your own symbol names.”

Comment: @JeremyL yes, I am sure. That guy is also using bad practice.

Comment: what about if the class is an UI object... I'd like to use some sort of prefix that indicate that it is UI object... but then if not use `UINodeView`, then is there a convention to use, such as 3 letters: `UIQ` or 4 letters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should **not** use the name `NSNode`.  Apple reserves `NS` prefix for its own use.

Second, just give your `Node` class its own enumerate message.

```
@interface Node : NSObject

- (void)enumerateChildrenUsingBlock:(void (^)(Node *child, NSUInteger childIndex, BOOL *stop))block;

// I prefer this shorter name style in my own classes:
- (void)forEachChild:(void (^)(Node *child, NSUInteger childIndex, BOOL *stop))block;
```

Implementing it is trivial:

```
@implementation Node

- (void)enumerateChildrenUsingBlock:(void (^)(Node *child, NSUInteger childIndex, BOOL *stop))block {
    BOOL stop = NO;
    block(self.leftChild, 0, &stop);
    if (!stop) {
        block(self.rightChild, 1, &stop);
    }
}
```

If you implement the `NSFastEnumeration` protocol, you can also write a for/in loop like this:

```
for (Node *child in parentNode) {
    // do something with child
}
```

You can implement `NSFastEnumeration` like this:

```
@interface Node : NSObject <NSFastEnumeration>
...

@implementation Node

- (NSUInteger)countByEnumeratingWithState:(NSFastEnumerationState *)state objects:(id *)stackbuf count:(NSUInteger)stackbufCount {
    // The compiler initializes state->state to 0 at the start of the for...in loop.
    // I use it to track which children have been returned.
    // 0 = no children returned yet
    // 1 = left children returned
    // 2 = both children returned

    state->itemsPtr = stackbuf;
    state->mutationsPtr = (__bridge unsigned long *)self;

    NSUInteger count = 0; // number of children I'm returning on this call
    if (state->state < 1 && count < stackbufCount) {
        stackbuf[count++] = self.leftChild;
        ++state->state;
    }
    if (state->state < 2 && count < stackbufCount) {
        stackbuf[count++] = self.rightChild;
        ++state->state;
    }

    return count;
}
```

Take a look at this article for more about fast enumeration: http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-04-16-implementing-fast-enumeration.html

Comment: This seems like massive overkill for an object that can only have 2 elements.

Comment: It might be overkill. How many places does he use the Node API? What performance requirements does he have?

Answer (score 3):

When you need to do something to both children you can always just use an array anyway

```
for (Node *node in @[self.leftChild, self.rightChild]) {
    // ...
}
```

And if you want to make it simpler, you can just define a method `- (NSArray *)children` that returns `@[self.leftChild, self.rightChild]`. But keeping the mutable properties as the distinct children is useful because it explicitly encodes the fact that your node only has 2 children instead of an unbounded number of children.

Comment: that looks nice... although if I just use `NSMutableArray`, will it make the class changeable in the future for N-children -- or just make it N-Children to begin with -- and just use it with a N = 2 as a binary tree?